# WMI: cant set my textbox value to ManagementBaseObject array

Tags: c#

Good day.

I have a problem declaring new string value with the value came from textbox1.text and the value of the textbox is 192.168.1.5
this is the code which is not working.

```
newIP["SubnetMask"] = new String[] { textBox1.Text };
```

Now i have string sampleip that i declared

```
string sampleip = "192.168.1.5";
newIP["SubnetMask"] = new String[] { sampleip  };
```

that code is working.

but the question is.

how the code works fine if the codes will be this one

```
newIP["SubnetMask"] = new String[] { textBox1.Text };
```

i will show you guys the whole code.

```
// this code for ip and subnet
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementBaseObject setIP;
            ManagementBaseObject newIP =
                objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

            string sampleip = "192.168.1.5";

            **newIP["SubnetMask"] = new String[] { textBox1.Text };**
            newIP["IPAddress"] = new String[] { textBox2.Text };

            setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }


    }
}
```

this is the value in my textbox1.text i have sample image here
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A804k.png)

thanks guys.

Comment: Are you sure the input has a valid value? Debug your code and inspect the value just before executing that line.

Comment: the input was correct.. and i gonna make sure i try to show it to messagebox..

Comment: i edit my question.. their you can see the value of my textbox sir @JeroenHeier

Comment: i try to this string sampleip = textBox1.Text;

            newIP["SubnetMask"] = new String[] { sampleip }; but still not working ..

Comment: Have you inspected the returned value of the "EnableStatic" method? Which is of type *HResult*. It will tell you if something went wrong. Also, since you are disabling the DHCP, you should also set the Gateway Address and at least one DNS Address. See the method calling specs [EnableStatic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390383(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Jimi is it working if the value is came from my database? and push it to the new String[] { sampleip } ???

Comment: @Jimi jimi. if i set the value of textbox is static string. sample. string x = "192.168.1.5"; then textbox1.text = x; then try to push it to the new string[] {textbox1.text} that work is fine.. how ever. if i retrieve the value in the database . there is no changes happen

Comment: What database? You mean, you set the value but reading it back shows no changes? Have you read what I wrote in the first comment: *Have you inspected the returned value of the "EnableStatic" method? Which is of type HResult.*. You have to read the value returned and confront it with the possible values that the method may return. One of which is *"Successful completion, reboot required"* (=1).

Comment: the process that i do is. i select the ip,subnet,gateway data in database. then after i select it the ip,subnet,gateway is set in textbox1,textbox2,textbox3. after i set it. i push the data in the newIP["SubnetMask"] = new String[] { textBox1.Text };**
            newIP["IPAddress"] = new String[] { textBox2.Text };